# Flowplayer playlist plugin issues with special characters in title

Tags: javascript, plugins, escaping, special-characters, flowplayer

I have a playlist for the flowplayer on the page. I am having problems with tracks having titles that include special characters. Currently I have the code below that works fine:

```
$(function(){
    $f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
        clip: {
            baseUrl: "http://localhost/gbc/"
        },
        playlist: [
            {   url: "media/20140724_agoodsong.mp3",
                name: "20140724_agoodsong.mp3",
                title: "this title works",
                class: "audio",
                id: "3"
            }
        ]
    });

    $f("player").playlist("div.playlist:first", {loop:true});
});
```

However, the second I put a special character in the title it does not work such as `title: "this doesn't work"`. There are no errors that I can tell; there's nothing in the developer tools console or in the Apache server logs. Everything displays fine, just when I click on the song to play the player goes black and nothing happens. I have tried putting back slashes in front of it to escape it like this `title: "this still doesn\'t work"` but it does not change anything. That's what made me think it has something to do with the way the Flowplayer Playlist plugin handles it. Since it takes those values in the JavaScript and inserts them into a template in the html like the following:

```
<div class="playlist">
    <ul class="${class}">
        <li>
            <img data-name="${name}" class="audio" src="images/delete.png" id="${id}" />
            <a href="${url}">
                ${title}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zy3Sc/)** that shows the problem. Currently it works, but add a special character of any kind in the title and it stops working. Even adding html codes like `&#39;` for an apostrophe stops it from working.

Does anyone know how I can include a title that has special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up getting it to work by escaping the special characters with unicode. So for an apostrophe I used `\u2019` in this case.

```
$(function(){
    $f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
        clip: {
            baseUrl: "http://localhost/gbc/"
        },
        playlist: [
            {   url: "media/20140724_agoodsong.mp3",
                name: "20140724_agoodsong.mp3",
                title: "this title work\u2019s",
                class: "audio",
                id: "3"
            }
        ]
    });

    $f("player").playlist("div.playlist:first", {loop:true});
});
```

You can see the above code working in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zy3Sc/2/)**.

---

While that fixed my initial problem, these titles are user inputs in my case so I had to find a way to find and convert the special characters to their unicode equivalents. After much googling I didn't really find anything that was concrete so I tried a different approach. I did away with using the template that the [flowplayer documentation](http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/playlist.html) uses and just printed the playlist out in the html myself. So now in the JavaScript I just set the base url for flowplayer and instantiate the playlist plugin.

```
$f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
    clip: {
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost/gbc/'
    }
});

$f("player").playlist("div.playlist:first", {loop:true});
```

And then in my PHP script I loop through and create each playlist item myself using the same format as the template I started with.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $id = $row['id'];               
        $name = $row['name'];
        $title = stripslashes($row['title']);
        $type = $row['type'];

        $class = "audio";
        if (strpos($type,'video') !== false) {
            $class = "video";
        }

        print "<ul class='$class'>
                <li>
                    <img data-name='$name' class='deleteAudio' src='images/delete.png' id='$id' />
                    <a href='media/$name'>
                        $title
                    </a>
                </li>
              </ul>";
}
```

And then in the page file I just include this script to print out the playlist.

```
<div class="playlist">
    <?php include "phpscripts/getAudio.php"; ?>
</div>
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it worked for me! Hopefully this will save someone else some time and frustration.